# DelegatingFilterProxy is registering on incorrect path

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have a Spring Boot application with custom spring security.
I am trying to change the path where springSecurityFilterChain is being registered.

I tried the following way:

Properties:

```
# spring
spring.application.name = rest
spring.main.web-environment = true

# security
security.basic.enabled=false

# management
management.port = 80
management.ssl.enabled = false
management.context-path = /actuator
management.security.enabled = false

# server
server.port = 443
server.ssl.enabled = true
server.ssl.key-alias = tomcat
server.ssl.key-store = /usr/app/.keystore
server.ssl.key-store-password = tomcat
```

Main:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.example")
public class RestApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(RestApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Web security config:

```
package com.example.security.config;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private TokenAuthenticationProvider tokenAuthenticationProvider;

    @Autowired
    private SSEAuthenticationProvider sseAuthenticationProvider;

    @Autowired
    private HMACAuthenticationProvider hmacAuthenticationProvider;

    @Autowired
    private CustomAuthenticationEntryPoint customAuthenticationEntryPoint;

    @Bean
    public SecurityContextRepository securityContextRepository() {
        return new NullSecurityContextRepository();
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenAuthenticationFilter tokenAuthenticationFilter() {
        return new TokenAuthenticationFilter();
    }

    @Bean
    public HMACAuthenticationFilter hmacAuthenticationFilter() {
        return new HMACAuthenticationFilter();
    }

    @Bean
    public SSEAuthenticationFilter sseAuthenticationFilter() {
        return new SSEAuthenticationFilter();
    }

    @Bean
    public CompositeFilter authFilters() {
        CompositeFilter filter = new CompositeFilter();
        filter.setFilters(Arrays.asList(hmacAuthenticationFilter(), tokenAuthenticationFilter()));
        return filter;
    }

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean securityFilterChainRegistration() {
        DelegatingFilterProxy delegatingFilterProxy = new DelegatingFilterProxy();
        delegatingFilterProxy.setTargetBeanName(AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer.DEFAULT_FILTER_NAME);
        FilterRegistrationBean registration = new FilterRegistrationBean(delegatingFilterProxy);
        registration.addUrlPatterns("/services/*");
        registration.setName(AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer.DEFAULT_FILTER_NAME);
        registration.setAsyncSupported(true);
        return registration;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .csrf().disable()
            .requiresChannel()
            .and()
                .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(customAuthenticationEntryPoint)
            .and()
                .anonymous()
            .and()
                .securityContext().securityContextRepository(securityContextRepository())
            .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/services/**").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/services/users/authentication").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/services/users").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/services/users/*/sessions/*").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/actuator/**").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/services/notifications").hasRole("USER")
                    .anyRequest().hasRole("USER")
            .and()
                .addFilterBefore(sseAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .addFilterBefore(authFilters(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(tokenAuthenticationProvider)
            .authenticationProvider(sseAuthenticationProvider)
            .authenticationProvider(hmacAuthenticationProvider);
    }
}
```

But in the log I still see:

```
2017-03-12 14:11:27.899  INFO 5 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'securityFilterChainRegistration' with a different definition: replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=restApplication; factoryMethodName=securityFilterChainRegistration; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in com.example.RestApplication] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.SecurityFilterAutoConfiguration; factoryMethodName=securityFilterChainRegistration; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/security/SecurityFilterAutoConfiguration.class]]
....
[ost-startStop-1] .s.DelegatingFilterProxyRegistrationBean : Mapping filter: 'springSecurityFilterChain' to: [/*]
```

At the same time I have different FilterRegistrationBeans, and they are correctly registered:

```
2017-03-12 14:11:35.669  INFO 5 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'headerHttpMethodOverrideFilter' to urls: [/services/*]
```

Could you please suggest a correct configuration?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Spring Boot doesn't support reconfiguring the path pattern of the security filter in this way as it's a rather unusual thing to do. It's recommended that the filter be configured to cover all paths and that you then use Spring Security's standard configuration mechanisms to control which paths are secured and which are not.

If you really want to customise the path of the filter, then you have a couple of options:

1. You could disable `SecurityFilterAutoConfiguration` using the `exclude` attribute on `@SpringBootApplication` and configure the filter yourself including setting its order and dispatcher types. This approach will mean that any filter-related `security.*` properties have no effect.
2. You could use a `BeanPostProcessor` to set the url patterns on the registration bean. You can identify the bean using its name which will be `springSecurityFilterChain`. This approach will mean that `security.*` properties can still be used.